# Check for page template on save_post hook

Tags: save-post, post-meta

I'm reading into the [save_post Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and I find that you need to check the $_REQUEST['post_meta_data'] in the edit window to hook into save_post.

I altered the example code:

```
function av_subscribe_set_parent($post_id){
/* in production code, $slug should be set only once in the plugin,
   preferably as a class property, rather than in each function that needs it.
 */
$slug = 'page';

/* check whether anything should be done */
$_POST += array("{$slug}_edit_nonce" => '');
if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    return;
}
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
    return;
}
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST["{$slug}_edit_nonce"],
                       plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
{
    return;
}

/* Request passes all checks; update the post's metadata */
if ($_REQUEST['_wp_page_template'] == 'av_comment_subscribe.php') {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_parent', 13570);
}
```

So basically, I'm checking if the page template is set to my custom template and then altering the post_parent meta data if true.

This is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the request value, before save and get an hint via wp_die()

```
add_action( 'save_post','wpse46583_save', 10, 2 );
function wpse46583_save( $post_id, $post ) {

    // verify this is not an auto save routine. 
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // You should check nonces and permissions here
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;

    if ( $_REQUEST['page_template'] !== 'page-contact.php' ) {
        // No page template assigned - do something here.
        wp_die( 'wrong template' );
    }

    return;
}
```

> see [Gist 3226847](https://gist.github.com/3226847)

Comment: I get the 'wrong template' error. I also tried with $_REQUEST['_wp_page_template'] with the same error. The template is definitely assigned to the page. Hm

Comment: The template string is really right?

Comment: absolutely, in my case I'm using av_comment_subscribe.php which resides along with all the other child-theme template files.

Comment: Also, I'm confused as to what exactly $_REQUEST is checking. Can it be any metadata? What about for example, 'category'? I'm trying to find a workaround...

Comment: Have you seen via `var_dump($_REQUEST)` was was inside after save page?

Comment: for debugging: use this `var_dump( get_page_templates() );` for get list of all template files and check the string; this is the string, there you use for the if statemant. I have also update the Gist, that you can use this directly.

Comment: Kind of a stupid question but how would I output this on the save_post hook? Your code has wp_die to output an error message but how would I output the var_dump?

Comment: If you save or update the page, then you go the error page via wp_die and see the var_dump().